# Hiding admin page as a subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a site that has an admin page (eg admin.php) that is normally accessed via mydomain.com/admin.php

What I was hoping to be able to do is to use htaccess to map
"admin.mydomain.com" to "mydomain.com/admin.php" in such a way that the user would never know that it was a 'file'.

That is, if someone externally tried to access "mydomain.com/admin.php", I want it to 404.

Now, for the even hard part: the admin.php page will want to serve links as "/admin.php?param=value", etc and so I'd need to look at the referrer (???) to let this work as expected.

can htaccess do this? Any idea on where to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have set up a record for `admin.mydomain.com` with the same IP Address as `mydomain.com` as well as the same `DocumentRoot`,

Then this can be done like this in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(admin\.) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} admin\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you are trying to do (or really why you absolutely need to have the page `mydomain.com/admin.php`).

If you are trying to "hide" it from the users, why not actually create a subdomain, place the file in the subdomain, implement security on the entire subdomain and then there is no need for messing around with redirections, referrers or query strings.

For security you might want to do something like [this](http://webdesign.about.com/od/htaccess/ht/hthtaccess.htm):

In your .htaccess put:

```
AuthUserFile /path/to/htpasswd/file/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName "MyDomain Admin Area"
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
```

Create the file .htpasswd using a generator such as [this](http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/)

Then you will have no need to hide the page from the user because without the correct username and password, they will get a 403.

Comment: The reason the file cannot be elsewhere is that I'm using a 3rd party cms and I'd need to duplicate the install...which may not actually be possible due to licensing.